# Cannot Query in Firestore Rules Using Claims

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In my firestore rules, this allows me to query a list of all of a user's "organizations":

```
match /organizations/{orgId}{
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

Where members is an array of user id's.

But, if I change this to work with claims:

```
match /organizations/{orgId}{
  allow read: if orgId in request.auth.token.organizations;
}
```

Where organizations is a list of organization id's.

It seems to work with:

```
match /organizations/{orgId}{
  allow read: if request.auth.token.organizations[orgId] == true;
}
```

It will let me access the document, but not a list of documents. Is there any way around this?

Comment: FYI: If you have additions or changes to make to your question, you can just edit the question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson still learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters). (Be sure to read the docs in that link.)  Also read more [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

When you perform a query on a collection (not a single document get), the filters on the query must absolutely match the requirements of the rules, before the contents of any documents are known.  The security rules will not remove individual documents from the results.  In this respect, Firestore queries are "all or nothing" - either all of the requested documents are known to match ahead of time, or the entire query fails.

What you have now suggests that each document ID should be read and individually compared to the list of organizations to determine which ones should be returned.  Since rules won't do this filtering, it simply simply rejects the query altogether.

What you should probably do instead is simply make one get() for each org ID in the user's claims.  It's definitely possible to read custom claims in the client app.

Comment: my backup was to do a single get. but why is it now working when I use a key/value pair?

Comment: What do you mean "when I use a key/value pair"?

Comment: i added to my question - like you specifically told me to do in your comment above?

Comment: OK, so, it sounds like your first question was answered (why doesn't that rule work).  If you have a second question about new code, please post that separately.  Stack Overflow is not a very good forum for ongoing lines of questioning.